# Gaussian curvature in polar coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, polar-coordinates, curvature

Find the expression for the Gauss curvature in the polar coordinates associated to the exponential map. I thought about using Gauss's lemma: if $(r,\theta)$ are polar coordinates in the tangent plane and followed by the exponential map from the tangent plane to the surface; so E=1 and F=0, but how to continue?